# Dojo nested requires on IE7 and IE8 causes Invalid Argument Exception

Tags: dojo

Here is the simplest example I could come up with.  I keep getting an Invalid Argument exception being thrown on the second require call in IE7 and IE8.  This works fine in IE9+, Chrome and Firefox.  Very frustrating.  Debugging this through IE developer tools has not been helpful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   require(["dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/domReady"],
      function(xhr){
         xhr("Servlet?arg=1")
           .then(function(data) {
              try {
                   test()
               } catch(e) {
                  cpb.consoleLog(e.number);
                  cpb.consoleLog(e.description);
                  throw e;
               }
          });
      });
  function test() {
      require(['dojox/charting/Chart'], function (Chart) {
           // simulate problem
      });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I moved up the test() function call so it was directly under function(xhr) and before the xhr call.  Everything seemed to process okay.  I'm wondering now if this is a problem calling requires in an ajax request.

Comment: I ended up just including a script tag and calling the resource straight from the server.  I should have thought of that sooner.

Comment: I'm having a similar and disgusting problem here: https://github.com/Esri/bootstrap-map-js/issues/37