# Esri bootstrap-map-js and Invalid argument error on IE 7/8

Tags: internet-explorer-7, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, dojo

I'm using this awesome project called [bootstrap-map-js](https://github.com/Esri/bootstrap-map-js/).

> A simple framework for building responsive mapping apps with ArcGIS
>   and Bootstrap.

Since Esri ArcGIS JavaScript API states that they [support IE7+](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/) I thought the amazing `bootstrap-map-js` project would also be compatible with `IE 7`. Maybe it is and the problem is in my code...

I'm getting an `Invalid Argument` error with no further info on `IE 11 Developer Tools` console window when simulating the page on `IE 7/8` document modes. `IE 9` onwards works great. All other browsers work great too! :) Only finicky IE refuses to work as always...

[image]

Looks like `dojo.require` is barking somewhere. See this related question: [Dojo nested requires on IE7 and IE8 causes Invalid Argument Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13074513/114029)

If I remove the reference to `bootstrapmap.js` and the `var map = ...` declaration, then the code works and I see `hey Leniel!` otherwise the code breaks and I see the `Invalid argument`. The code breaks in the call to `BootstrapMap.create`.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on with ***finicky*** `IE`? Is there anything I can do to see more from the error? As you see in the image, there's no message, description, etc. :(

Here's the minimum code I had to assemble to get to what was causing the error:

```
<!-- ArcGIS JavaScript API v3.8 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.8/3.8/init.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function init()
{
    require([
        "esri/map",
        "/myproject/Scripts/bootstrapmap.js",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"
    ], function(
        Map,
        BootstrapMap,
        FeatureLayer
    )
    {

        // Get a reference to the ArcGIS Map class
        var map = BootstrapMap.create("mapDiv", {
            basemap: "oceans",
            center: [-117.789, 33.543],
            zoom: 12
        });

        alert('hey Leniel!');

    });
}

dojo.addOnLoad(init);

</script>
```

---

I made some progress on this issue as you can read [here](https://github.com/Esri/bootstrap-map-js/issues/37).

I read [Configuring Dojo with dojoConfig](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/dojo_config/) and then added this before `ArcGIS JS API` script tag:

```
<!-- set Dojo configuration, load Dojo -->
<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        has: {
            "dojo-firebug": true
        },
        parseOnLoad: true,
        async: true
    };
</script>
```

Now I get a more descriptive error instead of only `Invalid argument` as before. `IE Dev Tools` shows this:

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.
File: init.js, Line: 136, Column: 65
```

This is line `136` in `init.js` when I click on the link provided by `IE Dev Tools`:

```
b;b=d[b]?"cssFloat"in f.style?"cssFloat":"styleFloat":b;if(3==k)return q?g(f,e):f.style[b]=e;for(var r in b)l.set(a,r,b[r]);return l.getComputedStyle(f)};return l})},"dojo/dom-geometry":function(){define(["./sniff","./_base/window","./dom","./dom-style"],function(b,n,k,m){function l(a,b,d,c,h,f){f=f||"px";a=a.style;isNaN(b)||(a.left=b+f);isNaN(d)||(a.top=d+f);0<=c&&(a.width=c+f);0<=h&&(a.height=h+f)}function r(a){return"button"==a.tagName.toLowerCase()||"input"==a.tagName.toLowerCase()&&"button"==
```

[image]

Sounds like `IE 7/8` is barking about some crazy `CSS` manipulation done by `ArcGIS JS API`.

Comment: @Louis you're absolutely right. `ArcGIS JS API` uses Dojo's own AMD loader as per their [`Get Dojo's doc`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/inside_dojoversion.html). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it connecting the dots...

Searched for `NaNpx` e's value as I had never seen that before. Found this [jQuery ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6524).

Followed the advice given there and changed that `return` in line `136`,

from:

```
return q?g(f,e):f.style[b]=e;
```

to:

```
return q?g(f,e):f.style[b]=(e=='NaNpx'?'0px':e);
```

Note: I'm using `jQuery 1.11.0` which [supports IE 7](http://jquery.com/browser-support/).

Comment: Leinel, this problem returned in 3.9 I believe. Please check the issue you made on GitHub, I added a comment there. Hope to hear from you soon.